# Aggregation and counting in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multiindex *pandas* dataframe like this

```
# df =
                      val
date       id          
2021-01-01 whatever1  0
           whatever2  1
           whatever3  0
           whatever4  3
           whatever5  2
2021-01-02 whatever2  0
           whatever7  3
2021-01-03 whatever3  0
           whatever4  0
...
```

and I want to count occurences of different values under the first index, like this,

```
            0 1 2 3

2021-01-01  2 1 1 1
2021-01-02  1 0 0 1
2021-01-03  2 0 0 0
...
```

How can I do it? My best try was this:

```
df.groupby(by='date', level=0).agg([lambda x: [np.count_nonzero(x==i) for i in range(df.values.max())]])

# result = 
                     val
                <lambda>
data                    
2021-01-01  [2, 1, 1, 1]
2021-01-02  [1, 0, 0, 1]
2021-01-03  [2, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use a cross tabulation:

```
pd.crosstab(df.index.get_level_values('date'), df['val'])
Out: 
val         0  1  2  3
row_0                 
2021-01-01  2  1  1  1
2021-01-02  1  0  0  1
2021-01-03  2  0  0  0
```